# How best to only sync some tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a OCA (C# Winforms) with these tables:

Rough outline:

- Users table - copy from server. user-id must remain the same
- Document table - copy each row to the server then remove local copy

I'm wondering what the best approach is here, and particularly if this is the kind of thing Microsoft's Sync Framework is good for?

Comment: What is the destination you are sync'ing to? SQL Compact??

Comment: At the moment it's a local SQL express database of identical schema - it probably should be SQL Compact though. I might change it. How does that affect what I'm asking though?

Comment: If you are talking SQL Express then I would suggest SQL replication is a better option. For SQL Compact then Sync Services is a good solution which I have used before. Be careful if you then decide to use Sync Services for devices as the performance is very poor.

Comment: I only want to sync some parts of the database - can I do that with replication?

Comment: Sure, take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165700%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to select/specify which tables you want to sync, even specify which columns.

for your second issue, a delete on the local copy will be uploaded as delete to the server as well.

if you're using SQL Express and you dont want the delete to propagate to the server, the quickest workaround just disable the delete/ trigger that updates the tracking tables.

Comment: When you say I can "even specify which columns" are you referring to Sync Framework or something else? Thanks.

Comment: sync framework... you dont have to sync the entire table if you dont want to...subset of columns or subset of rows via filters